# Update query in Access to update MANY columns from Null to value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database table with about 100 columns (bulky, I know). I have about half of these columns which I will need to update iteratively to set Is Null or "" values to "TBD".

I compiled all 50 some columns which need to be updated into an update query with Access SQL code that looked something like this...

```
UPDATE tablename
SET tablename.column1="TBD", tablename.column2="TBD", tablename.column3="TBD"....
WHERE tablename.column1 Is Null OR tablename.column1="" OR tablename.column2 Is Null OR tablename.column2="" OR tablename.column3 Is Null OR tablename.column3=""....
```

Two issues: This query with 50 columns receives a "query is too complex" error.

This query is also just functionally wrong...because I'm losing data within these columns due to the WHERE statement. Records that had values populated which I did not want to update are being updated because of the OR clause.

**My question is how can I go about updating all of these columns and setting their null or empty values to a particular value (in this case, "TBD")?**

I know that I can just use a select query to select the columns I need to update, run it, and just CTRL+H to find & replace "" to "TBD". However, I'm worried about the potential for this to introduce errors into my dataset. I also know I could also go through column by column and update these values via an update query. However, this would be quite time consuming with 50+ columns & the iterative updates which I need to run on the entire dataset.

I'm leaning towards this latter route. I am still wondering if there are any other scripted options which I can build into a query to overcome such an issue, and that leads me here to you.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could just run 50 queries:

```
UPDATE table SET column1="TBD" WHERE column1 IS NULL OR column1 = "";
```

An optimization could be:

- Create a temporary table which determines which rows actually would need an update: Concatenate all column values such that a single NULL or empty would result in an record in your temp table. This way you only have to scan the base table once.
- Use the keys from that table to focus on those rows only.

Etc.
That is safe and only updates your empty values (where as your previous query would have updated all columns unless you would have checked every value first with an `IFNULL`). 
This query style also does not run into the **too complex** issue

Answer (score 0):

You could issue one query as:

```
UPDATE tablename
    SET column1 = iif(column1 is null or column1 = "", "TBD", column1),
        column2 = iif(column2 is null or column2 = "", "TBD", column2),
        . . .;
```

If you don't mind potentially updating all rows, you can leave out the `where` clause.

Comment: Nz doesn't trigger on `""`, as far as I know. You haven't accounted for non-null empty strings in your solution. You could go `IIF(nz(column1) = "", "TBD", column1)`

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth . . . `nz()` doesn't treat `""` as `NULL`.  I fixed the answer.